# Trying to open Firefox via Selenium fails when running from VSCode

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, visual-studio-code, geckodriver

I'm trying to open Firefox via Selenium and it fails. It worked fine with Chrome, but when I tried Firefox I can't get it to work. It fails when trying to create the webdriver object, throwing `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process`

The code I execute is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import json
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
```

with the geckodriver file in the same folder as the python file.

After searching online I found it might be because of incompatible versions of geckodriver and Firefox but I have Firefox 72.0.1-64bit and use the geckodriver v0.26.0-linux64.

Edit: I have found that the problem does NOT occur when running normally from terminal, but only when running the python code from the VSCode terminal. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add all the lines of code that are above this line?

Comment: @Jortega I updated the question. The functions are called later in main and the parameters are for the functions. They shouldn't matter much.

Comment: How are you calling this file?

Comment: Try running it with `{global parameters}` and `{some functions}` commented out.

Comment: It is opening firefox for me if I comment out `{global parameters}`, `{some functions}` and edit my `executable_path` to my local location.

Comment: @Jortega Thank you, I got it to run :)

Comment: @Jortega Ok so I figured the problem out now, it's when I run it from the VSCode terminal that it fails. If I run it from a normal terminal it works (same command: `python3 file.py`.

Comment: Interesting, I usually do not run anything from the VSCode terminal.  I would recommend PyCharm for Python.

Comment: @Jortega Your comment _...Try running it with {global parameters} and {some functions} commented out..._ possibly would have been one of the best answers for Selenium/VSCode users. I would suggest to construct an answer with these information for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB a summary of the comments has been added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with `{global parameters}` and `{some functions}` commented out.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import json
import os

#{global parameters}
#{some functions}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
```

I can execute this file from the command line by `cd` ing to the location of the file and running `python file_name.py` assuming the text above is in a file called `file_name.py`.

Not that attempting to run this from the VSCode terminal was not successful for the asker of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, so I hope you'll tolerate my ignorance of suchAfter a week of struggling with the same error, I found that I needed the following line typed at the command line ($) of the environment I was using:

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```

In my case, this allowed Visual Studio Code 1.46.1 to open an output screen on my console when running Python 3.6.9 with Selenium 3.141.0 and Pytest 5.4.3 modules. Will it work for you? Don't know. It was such a simple thing that worked. Not sure why. Something to do with session display output routing? NOTE: When I want to run the Python program using the Selenium webdriver WITHOUT the session display output coming to my console, I can run the webdriver "headless".

Hope this helps more than hinders...